# Is there a way during replication to turn off the automatic start of the backup server when the live server fails?

Tags: activemq-artemis

I have a Live - Backup pair with the replication HA policy. I would like to manage the replica startup myself when the live server fails, leaving only data replication between them. Is it possible to somehow achieve this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the main goals of the live/backup pair is failover (i.e. automatically starting the backup when the live fails). There is no way to disable this functionality and still use a live/backup pair.

However, you could potentially use a [`broker-connection`](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/amqp-broker-connections.html) with the ["mirror"](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/amqp-broker-connections.html#mirroring) configuration to get the results you want.